# Who first used Banach's Contraction Principle to prove the Inverse Function Theorem?

Tags: mathematics, discoveries, real-analysis

The most common proof of the [Inverse Function Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) in textbooks relies on the [Banach fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

> **QUESTION.** 
>   It is possible to say, using historical references, which mathematician came up with the idea of using Banach's Contraction Principle to prove the inverse function theorem? If not, what is the earliest known source where such proof appeared?

I did a search on the Mathematics history books specialized in the subject, but I did not find any clues. For example:

- Krantz, Steven G.; Parks, Harold R. [The implicit function theorem. History, theory, and applications. Birkhäuser Boston, Inc., Boston, MA, 2002.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/146145980X)
- Dontchev, Asen L.; Rockafellar, R. Tyrrell [Implicit functions and solution mappings. A view from variational analysis. Springer Monographs in Mathematics. Springer, Dordrecht, 2009](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387878203)

Comment: Hi MathOverview, and welcome to HSM. Please note that crossposting on different SE sites is not encouraged. Instead, one should flag the original post and ask the moderators for a migration.

Comment: @Danu So I must ask the MSE moderators to migrate my original question in MSE for HSM?

Comment: Yes, that would be the correct way to proceed.